# Physics Engine Spring Bug

Tags: physics-engine

So I've been working on a 2d physics engine that supports polygons and circles. I've utilized the separating axis theorem for all collision combinations except for circle-circle. Here is the basic format of the engine:

*NOTE: NOT ACTUAL CODE

Advance all bodies.

```
for every body a
{
   Vector2 sum = Vector2.Zero;
   for every body b where b != a
   {
     sum += a.collides(b).MinimumTranslationVector;
   }
   a.Position += sum;
   a.velocity += sum;
}
```

Here is a video of the problem I am having: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSZeuP4AiQ0&feature=youtu.be

The error is the spring effect that is seen near the beginning. I've been racking my brain trying to think of the problem and I've come up with nothing. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Are you referring to the bounciness within the stack?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the bounciness within the stack.

Comment: This can be caused by a ton of things. Object size, mass, gravity, your collision handling... it's a fairly normal occurrence. I'm not sure how you handle your collisions, but if the new top "box" collides with the top of the stack, do you just handle this new collision, or do you also iteratively account for the new collisions down the stack?

Comment: I just iteratively account for the the new collision down the stack. Currently, I think the problem is the box collides with the top of the stack, but the top of the stack is shifted down rather than the box being shifted up.

Also my engine is currently in its initial phases. I am not accounting for mass, momentum, rotation, etc.

Comment: If you want realism your 'force' need to affect the 'speed' and not the 'position'.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this pseudocode correctly, whenever two bodies collide, each one undergoes a change in position and velocity. Yet when a falling box hits a resting box, you want the resting box to remain stationary.

1. I think you should reconsider your basic collision physics. Real collisions don't work like that.

   Consider making the timestep smaller. After all, real objects *are* elastic, but "rigid" objects vibrate too quickly for us to see; the rubbery stack of blocks looks like a stack of rigid objects in slow motion, so if you speed them up they'll look more rigid. The large-scale motion is already correct.

   If you want objects to be impenetrable, you must implement special rules to that effect. I don't know whether the walls are impenetrable, but that would be a good place to start.